# cannot open a new android project on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

i tryed to start a new android project on ubuntu 13.04 but when i'm starting my project it gives me a compillation error.
the error is with the R library ("R cannot be resolved to a variable").
when i tries to import the import android.R it just give me another error.
any one maybe know what is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally shouldn't manually import R. If `Organize Imports` (ctrl-shift-o) causes it to be added to the list of imports, that often indicates an inconsistency between the package name used in the package statement at the top of your source file and the package name used in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Make sure those two match.